# Internal server error when clicking button in flask app

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I'm new to Flask and trying to build my first simple app which takes a text input and upon the user clicking a button I want it to display the text that was entered.

My HTML page loads successfully and I can enter the text into the input.
However, when I click the button I get a new page showing the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Predict Code</h1>

            <form action="http://localhost:5000/predict" method="post">
                <label form="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" id="description" name="description">
                <button type="submit">Predict Code</button>

            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            {{ prediction_text }}

    </body>
</html>
```

My flask app .py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

# create the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# what html should be loaded as the home page when the app loads?
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('app_frontend.html')

# define the logic for reading the inputs from the WEB PAGE, 
# running the model, and displaying the prediction
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():

    # get the description submitted on the web page
    a_description = request.form.values()
    return render_template('Description entered: {}'.format(a_description))

# boilerplate flask app code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():

    # get the description submitted on the web page
    a_description = request.form.values()
    # THIS LINE:
    return render_template('Description entered: {}'.format(a_description))
```

You're trying to render a template, but passing in a string, not a template.

If you want to return just the string, do this:

```
return 'Description entered: {}'.format(a_description)
```

If you look at the python error output you will see:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: Description entered: <generator
> object MultiDict.values at 0x000001CEEEF83620>

**EDIT**

To answer the additional comment question. To get the value of the form post you will need to change your line from:

```
a_description = request.form.values()
```

to:

```
a_description = request.form.get('description')
```

Comment: This worked - partially. it no longer errors but it is not displaying the value of a_description. Its just displaying 'Description entered:'. Do you know why its not getting the value that was entered in the text box?'

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Its just displaying 'Description entered:'. Do you know why its not getting the value that was entered in the text box?'

Comment: @code_to_joy updated my answer to include this question. If you have more issues, it will be best to submit a new SO question vs in comments :) Happy Coding!